# How To Insert created_time and update_time in Databse?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid

I Have Created a Custom Module.
In This Module Have a Field Like  created_time and update_time.
How To Insert That Date In Database Custom Table?

Here Is My Code..

**C:\xampp2\htdocs\mymagento\app\code\local\Rushikesh\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Edit\Tab\Form.php**

```
<?php

class Rushikesh_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Module_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('module_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('module')->__('Item information')));

        $fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('module')->__('Title'),
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'title',
        ));

        /* $dateTimeFormatIso = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);
        $fieldset->addField('date_and_time', 'datetime', array(
            'label'    => Mage::helper('module')->__('Date time'),
            'title'    => Mage::helper('module')->__('Date time'),
            'time'     => true,
            'name'     => 'date_and_time',
            'image'    => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
            'format'   => $dateTimeFormatIso,
            'required' => true,
        )); */

        $dateFormatIso = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);
        $fieldset->addField('created_time', 'date', array(
            'name'      => 'created_time',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('module')->__('Created Time'),
            'image'     => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
            'format'    => $dateFormatIso,
            'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled,
            'class'     => 'validate-date validate-date-range date-range-custom_theme-from'
        ));

        $dateFormatIso = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);
        $fieldset->addField('update_time', 'date', array(
            'name'      => 'update_time',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('module')->__('Update Time'),
            'image'     => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
            'format'    => $dateFormatIso,
            'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled,
            'class'     => 'validate-date validate-date-range date-range-custom_theme-from'
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('status', 'select', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('module')->__('Status'),
            'name'      => 'status',
            'values'    => array(
                array(
                    'value'     => 1,
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('module')->__('Active'),
                ),

                array(
                    'value'     => 0,
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('module')->__('Inactive'),
                ),
            ),
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('content', 'editor', array(
            'name'      => 'content',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('module')->__('Content'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('module')->__('Content'),
            'style'     => 'width:98%; height:400px;',
            'wysiwyg'   => false,
            'required'  => true,
        ));

        if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getModuleData() )
        {
            $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getModuleData());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setModuleData(null);
        } elseif ( Mage::registry('module_data') ) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::registry('module_data')->getData());
        }
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

**C:\xampp2\htdocs\mymagento\app\code\local\Rushikesh\Module\controllers\Adminhtml\ModuleController.php**

```
<?php

class Rushikesh_Module_Adminhtml_ModuleController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
{

    protected function _initAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('module/items')
            ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Items Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));
        return $this;
    }   

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->_initAction();       
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/adminhtml_module'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function editAction()
    {
        $moduleId     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $moduleModel  = Mage::getModel('module/module')->load($moduleId);

        if ($moduleModel->getId() || $moduleId == 0) {

            Mage::register('module_data', $moduleModel);

            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->_setActiveMenu('module/items');

            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));
            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'));

            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

            $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/adminhtml_module_edit'))
                 ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/adminhtml_module_edit_tabs'));

            $this->renderLayout();
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('module')->__('Item does not exist'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }

    public function newAction()
    {
        $this->_forward('edit');
    }

    public function saveAction()
    {
        if ( $this->getRequest()->getPost() ) {
            try {
                $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
                $moduleModel = Mage::getModel('module/module');

                $moduleModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                    ->setTitle($postData['title'])
                    ->setContent($postData['content'])
                    ->setStatus($postData['status'])
                    ->save();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setModuleData(false);

                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setModuleData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
        if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') > 0 ) {
            try {
                $moduleModel = Mage::getModel('module/module');

                $moduleModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                    ->delete();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully deleted'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your `saveAction` as below

```
public function saveAction()
    {
        if ( $this->getRequest()->getPost() ) {
            try {
                $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
                $moduleModel = Mage::getModel('module/module');

                $moduleModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                    ->setTitle($postData['title'])
                    ->setContent($postData['content'])
                    ->setStatus($postData['status'])
                    ->setUpdateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
                    if(!$this->getRequest()->getParam('id')){
                        $moduleModel->setCreatedTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
                    }
                    $moduleModel->save();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setModuleData(false);

                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setModuleData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
```